# Retrieving lagged values within groups in R dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, mutate

I am working with a matched employer-employee dataset with both worker and firm-level variables. The following table illustrates a portion of what I see:

```
df <- structure(list(WorkerID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), FirmID = c(1234L, 1234L, 1234L, 1234L, 1234L, 
4321L, 4321L, 9678L, 9678L, 4321L, 5678L, 5678L, 5678L), Year = c(2003L, 
2004L, 2005L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L), Wage = c(1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1200L, 0L, 
1250L, 1250L, 735L, 0L, 0L, 780L, 780L, 0L), Separation = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

| Worker ID | Firm ID | Year | Wage | Separation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | 2003 | 1000 | 0 |
| 1 | 1234 | 2004 | 1000 | 0 |
| 1 | 1234 | 2005 | 1000 | 0 |
| 2 | 1234 | 2004 | 1200 | 0 |
| 2 | 1234 | 2005 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 4321 | 2006 | 1250 | 0 |
| 2 | 4321 | 2007 | 1250 | 0 |
| 3 | 9678 | 2003 | 735 | 0 |
| 3 | 9678 | 2004 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 4321 | 2005 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 5678 | 2006 | 780 | 0 |
| 3 | 5678 | 2007 | 780 | 0 |
| 3 | 5678 | 2008 | 0 | 1 |

The variable separation indicates whether the employee left the firm at the observed year (i.e. the value 1 implies unemployed). Any given employee can have multiple separations on any given year, which is indicative of tenures of less than a year before separation. What I need to do is to capture the last wage of unemployed individuals and store those in a variable that equals the last wage received if the individual is observed to be unemployed, or the current wage otherwise. For example, individual 2 was unemployed in 2005, and his last wage was 1200 in 2004. Individual 3, on the other hand, was unemployed in 2004 and 2005, whereby his last wage was 735 for both 2004 and 2005. The problem I'm having is dealing with an arbitrary number of consecutive unemployment periods.

I was able to implement a solution that works when individuals spend, at most, one period unemployed:

```
df %>%
group_by(Worker ID)
mutate(last_wage = ifelse(Separation = 1 & lag(Separation)=0, lag(Wage),Wage))
```

What I need is something that gets me the last wage of the employee for any observed period of unemployment.

Answer (score 0):

We can to it this way:

```
library(dplyr) #>= 1.1.0

df %>% 
  mutate(sep_group = cumsum(Separation == 1),
         last_wage = ifelse(Separation == 1, 
                            last(Wage[sep_group == lag(sep_group, default = 0)]), 
                            Wage), .by=WorkerID, .keep="unused")
```

```
   WorkerID FirmID Year sep_group last_wage
1         1   1234 2003         0      1000
2         1   1234 2004         0      1000
3         1   1234 2005         0      1000
4         2   1234 2004         0      1200
5         2   1234 2005         1      1250
6         2   4321 2006         1      1250
7         2   4321 2007         1      1250
8         3   9678 2003         0       735
9         3   9678 2004         1       780
10        3   4321 2005         2       780
11        3   5678 2006         2       780
12        3   5678 2007         2       780
13        3   5678 2008         3       780
```